# How to install Browser source plugin in obs(Open Broadcaster Software) studio

Tags: obs-studio

How can I install the [browser source plugin](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/clr-browser-source-plugin-obs-classic-only.22/) in [obs (Open Broadcaster Software) studio](https://obsproject.com/)?

Comment: What's "obs studio" and about which browser plug-in are you talking?

Comment: the obs studio software is used for creating facebook live poll reaction

Comment: Where is the obs-qtwebkit directory? How do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Browser source for OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/browser-plugin.115/) webpage says:

> There is not currently a Linux build of this browser plugin, but in the meantime bazukas has built [obs-qtwebkit](https://github.com/bazukas/obs-qtwebkit), another browser source based on qtwebkit.

Using the latest version of OBS Studio from ppa:obsproject/obs-studio (currently version 0.16.2) will simplify the installation of obs-qtwebkit.

#### Installation

> Make sure you have necessary dependencies installed, which are obs-studio and qt5 and qt5-webkit development packages. You may need to set OBS_INCLUDE and OBS_LIB env variables (see Makefile).
>
> On Ubuntu 16.04 you may need to install the developer libraries to compile.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev  
> sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
> ```
>
> Run `make` in the obs-qtwebkit directory to build the plugin. If your OBS version is < 0.11.2, run `OBS_PLUGIN_BUILD_OLD=1 make`
>
> Run `make install` to copy plugin binaries into `$HOME/.config/obs-studio/plugins`. If your OBS version is < 0.11.1, run `OBS_PLUGIN_INSTALL_OLD=1 make install`

Comment: These instructions are a bit out of date. Go here for current: https://github.com/bazukas/obs-linuxbrowser

Answer (score 1):

The browser plugin does not come with the version of obs that comes with ubuntu studio.  To fix this, `sudo apt-get remove obs-studio ; sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the default version, then install the version from OBS's own PPA. See their website for instructions: https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux

Comment: best answer for me, allowed me to get OBS  26.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ( with the new integrated browser source feature ) , working great !